# Puppet: exec onlyif value is not equal

Tags: centos, puppet, exec

I have a script that really only needs to be run one time on a server, i.e. at deployment time, but figured it would be best to have Puppet manage it.  The script remaps several legacy user id's that conflict with local system users.

The way I check this is if the gopher user has the default uid of 13.  If so, then I need to run my remapping script.

```
exec { "change_uid":
   command  => "/script/to/run.sh",
   provider => 'shell',
   path => [ "/bin", "/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/local/sbin" ],
   onlyif   => "test `/usr/bin/id -u gopher` -eq 13; echo $?",
}
```

I've tried several different permutations of the above `onlyif` check, but the exec always gets fired on the agent.

When I run that command directly on the command line, it returns either 0 or 1.  It could be related to the fact that bash [returns 0 when true and 1 when false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933843/why-0-is-true-but-false-is-1-in-bash), but I think its more likely that I'm misunderstanding the way `onlyif` works.

How can I have this exec fire when the gopher's uid=13?  I'm open to alternative ways to implement what I'm trying to accomplish here.

**UPDATE**

I dropped the echo part.  The final working solution is:

```
exec { "change_uid":
   command  => "/script/to/run.sh",
   path     => [ "/bin", "/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/local/sbin" ],
   onlyif   => "test `id -u gopher` -eq 13",
}
```

Making use of the `ralsh` commmand was helpful in testing, thanks @Daniel C. Sobral.  I'm marking @Daniel's as the accepted answer since that was the main issue, besides my misunderstanding of a few concepts, plus he answered first.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try removing the `echo $?` at the end?

That part will always make the whole thing `return 0`.

Comment: Yup, I tried it in puppet with/without.  Without the echo it returns nothing when tried via cmd line, regardless of how it evaluates, so I thought it may be needed.

Comment: the onlyif uses the return value of the command, not the output

Comment: OK so when I try out `test ...` on my linux command line (bash) as I have it written in my question above, the "echo $?" spits out a return value (0 or 1).  Without the echo portion, nothing is returned.  Isn't "echo $?" supposed to give you the return value of a command?

Comment: @Banjer `echo $?` *prints* the return value of a command, and returns 0. `onlyif` needs the return value, so if you add that `echo`, it will always receive `0`.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `onlyif` limits process execution to when the command pointed by `onlyif` returns success (`0`). For example:

```
dcs@shadowfax:~/tmp$ ls -l test
ls: cannot access test: No such file or directory
dcs@shadowfax:~/tmp$ ralsh exec "/bin/echo ok" onlyif="/usr/bin/test -f test"
exec { '/bin/echo ok':
  returns => ['0'],
}
dcs@shadowfax:~/tmp$ touch test
dcs@shadowfax:~/tmp$ ralsh exec "/bin/echo ok" onlyif="/usr/bin/test -f test"
notice: /Exec[/bin/echo ok]/returns: executed successfully
exec { '/bin/echo ok':
  returns => 'notrun',
}
```

So, when the file does not exist, it doesn't do anything. When I create the file, it displays a `notice` to the effect that `/bin/echo ok` was executed.

Ignore that `returns` stuff.

Anyway, since you ended the `onlyif` command with an `echo`, and `echo` always return success, then your `exec` always get executed. Remove that `echo` and leave only the `test` command.